# How can you make a shape in html with css

Tags: html, css

How can you make shapes using a single HTML element? Any CSS technique can be used as long as it's supported in at least one browser.

Examples of shapes would be a round shape, a triangle, six-angled and so on.

Comment: I'm not even sure what the question is, but `border-radius: 50%; -moz-border-radius: 50%;` may be one of the answers...

Comment: first round shape but its done with border radius. then now i m trying  to make triangle...

Comment: i got but i think its just Firefox browser only but for all browser u know how to create css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhs4d/) with some pure html/css shapes:
 - 2 triangles using a span border
 - a circle with the help of border-radius

Disclaimer: I was inspired from the old google application/menu bar.

Source:

html

```
An CSS triangle pointing down:
<span class="delta_down"></span><br>
An CSS triangle pointing up:
<span class="delta_up"></span><br>
Circle:
<span class="circle"></span>
```

css

```
span.delta_down {
        border-color: #C0C0C0 transparent transparent;
        border-style: solid dashed dashed;
        border-width: 5px 5px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0;
        height: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        padding-top: 1px;
        position: relative;
        top: -1px;
        width: 0;
}

span.delta_up {
        border-color: transparent transparent #C0C0C0;
        border-style: dashed dashed solid;
        border-width: 0 5px 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0;
        height: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        padding-top: 1px;
        position: relative;
        top: -1px;
        width: 0;
}

span.circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

http://css3shapes.com/ has instructions on how to make a lot of shapes in CSS.

But seriously, there are better solutions to drawing shapes in the browser than using CSS.

Most of the shapes shown in the site above only work in modern browsers because they use CSS3 techniques that aren't available in browsers like IE8. (So if you want to do this in old versions of IE, the answer is forget about it).

But the same browsers that support those shapes also all support other technologies like SVG, which allow you to draw any shapes you like, without the restrictions of working around a box shape.

So the short answer is yes, it can be done, but SVG will give you much better results.

Comment: but without use images can i give all browser support including ie low  version??

Comment: +1 great resource, for example I use similar things for a intranet, because I can control what browser(s) are used :)

Comment: @parkin - no, that's my point: most of the CSS shapes that are shown require features like `border-radius` or `:before` and `:after` which aren't available in older browsers. They loading that page in IE7 and see how many of them are rendered correctly. Very few, I'd bet.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with pure HTML and CSS. But you can use a canvas element and draw all shapes with JavaScript.

[This basic tutorial](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/) may help you.